# Programmatically access git data

Tags: python, node.js, git

How to retrieve file, commit etc. info from bare git repo? When I have created a git server using `git init --bare` command there are `branches/  config  description  HEAD  hooks/  info/  objects/  refs/` created by default. How can I retrieve file list or their content , commit info from server side ?  it will be really helpful if the solution or example will be in nodejs or python .

Comment: Pragmatically or programmatically?

Comment: sorry bad auto-correct  :(

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html might be useful

Comment: Above link returns a 404, try this one now:  http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [git server side hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375283/git-server-side-hooks)

Comment: You could use the library at: https://libgit2.github.com/
It has bindings to a number of languages, including python and node.js